# Case statement that does nothing if When is not true

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update a table that has ,unique accountID's, from a table that contains accountID's that occur more than once. So for example I have accountID 1 in table B once and accountID 1 in table A that occurs 5 times.

So essentially I am going from multiple rows updating to one row with all the data on that one row.

Example:

Table A has the multiple records per accountID

```
accountID  site  hard  soft     
1           12     20   0 
1           13     30   10
1           14     40   0
```

I need to update table B that only has the accountID and no other data. And looks like this:

```
accountID   site12_hard site12_soft  site13_hard site13_soft  site14_hard site14_soft
1
```

So I linked on accountID and did case statements for all the fields. Like this:

```
update table B set

site12_hard = case when site  = 12 then hard else 0 end,
site12_soft = case when site  = 12 then soft else 0 end,


from table A inner join table B on accountID = accountID
```

This isn't working right because the one to many link on accountID causes the case statement to evaluate each occurrence of that accountID. So it may update correctly on site12_hard but then when it moves to the next record of accountID = 1 it is no longer site = 12 so it updates to zero.

I need a way for the case statement to do nothing if the "when" is not true. Or I need a completely different method to update this table.

Comment: Thanks for editing this post. I couldn't figure out how to aling the table examples.

Comment: Either filter rows you don't want to update with a `WHERE` clause or set the column equal to itself (i.e. current value, no change).

Comment: Use `..when 12 then hard else site12_hard...`.

Comment: I guess you could use a sub-query like: `(SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableA A
                                            WHERE B.accountID  = A.accountID 
                                            AND   A.site       = 12))` instead of the join.

Comment: I tried Yuck's advice because it seemed reasonable but it didn't work. It seems that as soon as the case is satisfied and updates a field for a given accountID  it moves on.

Answer (score 0):

I have just made for only `site 12 & 13` similarly `site 14` has to be done. Try this..

```
UPDATE B
SET    site12_hard = a.site12_hard,
       site12_soft = a.site12_soft,
       site13_hard = a.site13_hard,
       site13_soft = a.site13_soft
FROM   tableB B
       INNER JOIN (SELECT accountID,
                          Max(CASE WHEN [site] = 12 THEN hard END) site12_hard,
                          Max(CASE WHEN [site] = 12 THEN soft END) site12_soft,
                          Max(CASE WHEN [site] = 13 THEN hard END) site13_hard,
                          Max(CASE WHEN [site] = 13 THEN soft END) site13_soft
                   FROM   tableA
                   GROUP  BY accountID) a
               ON a.accountID = b.accountID
```